# gdb-multiarch command not found

Tags: rhel, gcc, gdb, assembly

I have installed QEMU in RHEL for running the assembly programs in ARM. I have successfully installed QEMU and ARM. However, for debugging we are thinking to use GDB. I want to install the **GDB-Multiarch** in RHEL. I have installed GDB and when I run the command **GDB** I am getting the GDB shell successfully. However, I need to use the **GDB-Multiarch** and I am not able to run this command. To successfully run an assembly program, I need to execute the below command.

```
qemu-system-arm -S -s -M versatilepb -daemonize -m 128M -d in_asm,cpu,exec -kernel hello_world.bin ; gdb-multiarch --batch --command=hello_world.gdb
```

In the above command, I am getting the error as gdb-multiarch command as not found. I am really new to this environment and I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, "not found" means just that - that command most probably doesn't exist on your system. You may need to install the appropriate package before you can use that command.

Comment: In Ubuntu, we are able to give apt-get gdb-multiarch and the installation takes place. So, in RHEL the package for gdb-multiarch is not available. So, I installed the latest gdb rpm from [this](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) link. I am still getting the command not found error only.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there... I don't use RHEL. It is possible that this command is simply not available for RHEL, because the repositories of RHEL are as far as I know much smaller than those of Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but I just encountered this problem and found a solution. First of all, as mentioned, the gdb-multiarch package is available in Debian distributions but not in RHEL (the current version is RHEL 9) until now. I am using RHEL 7 and the solution below is valid for RHEL 7, but you can find a solution for other RHEL versions by installing similar packages.

1. install **devtoolset-11**(If you can't find devtoolset-11 with yum, you can download it directly from this [***link***](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/devtoolset-11-11.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html))
2. If you have previously installed an older gdb package, you need to activate the devtoolset-11 gdb version. To do this, run the "`scl enable devtoolset-11 bash`" command
3. Check the gdb version with "`gdb -v`". Result should be ;

> "GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 10.2-6.el7
>
> Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc."

4. Start the gdb session with the "`gdb`" command
5. Run the command to connect remote target :"`target remote localhost:1234`"
6. If you don't get an error, you are ready to debug.